# Using one MongoDB connection in multiple goroutines

Tags: mongodb, go

My go code is making a connection to MongoDB like this:

```golang
uri := "mongodb://localhost:27017"
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
defer cancel()
client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, options.Client().ApplyUIR(uri))
if err != nil {
        panic(err)
}
```

I want to create a couple of goroutines that regularly queries the database, and not sure if making every goroutine uses `client` is safe. What would be the most conventional way to make multiple goroutines interact with the same database?

Answer (score 2):

Single client instance is safe to use in multiple goroutines. From the docs:

> Client is a handle representing a pool of connections to a MongoDB deployment. It is safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines.